# SQLite3 Select from two different Tables

Tags: sql, sqlite

I want to create a new table using SQLite3 that selects the name of an Album - then from another table, grab all the tracks that have the albumID foreign key and count them. Is there an easy way to do this? Thanks

```
        CREATE TABLE Album
    (
        AlbumID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
        Title TEXT NOT NULL,
        ArtistID INTEGER NOT NULL,
        FOREIGN KEY (ArtistID) REFERENCES Artist (ArtistID)
                    ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
    );

CREATE TABLE Track
(
    TrackID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    Name TEXT NOT NULL,
    AlbumID INTEGER,
    MediaTypeID INTEGER NOT NULL,
    GenreID INTEGER,
    Composer TEXT,
    Millisecond INTEGER NOT NULL,
    Byte INTEGER,
    UnitPrice REAL NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (AlbumID) REFERENCES Album (AlbumID)
                ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
    FOREIGN KEY (GenreID) REFERENCES Genre (GenreID)
                ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
    FOREIGN KEY (MediaTypeID) REFERENCES MediaType (MediaTypeID)
                ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
);
```

Comment: Hint:  `JOIN`.  That is how you get information from multiple tables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should accomplish what you want:

```
SELECT a.Title, COUNT(a.Title)
FROM Album AS a
  JOIN Track AS b ON b.AlbumID = a.AlbumID
GROUP BY a.AlbumID
ORDER BY a.Title;
```

Comment: Thanks! That worked, but is there anyway to maintain the original width of the Album Title?

Comment: What do you mean by the original width?  The text type has an unspecified width.